right-to-left lists with l3doc
I've run into a couple of problems with typesetting my documentation with the l3doc class. Here's the first:
When typesetting a right-to-left list with a \leftmargin, no margin is inserted. This does not happen with the article class.
How can I work around this?
MWE
%! TeX Program = lualatex
\documentclass{l3doc} % compare with article class
\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=lists]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, main]{american}
\babelprovide[import, mapdigits]{persian}
\babelfont[persian]{rm}[Renderer = Harfbuzz]{Amiri}
\begin{document}
\begin{list}{\leftmargin 1cm}
  \item\relax
    123
\end{list}

\medskip
\hrule

\selectlanguage{persian}

\begin{list}{\leftmargin 1cm}
\item\relax
  123
\end{list}
\end{document}

Output with l3doc

Output with article


well l3doc is meant for the l3 documentation, and that is not in bidi ;-). You could try \cs_set_eq:NN  \list \__codedoc_oldlist:nn before babel, then babel can patch the list command, but this will loose the \listparindent=0pt inserted by l3doc.

You only need \shapemode to be at the correct number, probably \AddToHook{cmd/list/before}{\ifnum\pardirection=\pagedirection\else\shapemode=2\fi} should do the trick.

For simplicity, by default \parshape mirrors left and right indents only when \pagedirection is right to left, luckily it can be controlled manually using the \shapemode   register. When you use \parshape for right to left paragraphs in left to right page, you probably want the indents to be switched, so set \shapemode to 2 (see section 3.3.4 of LuaTeX's manual).
%! TeX Program = lualatex
\documentclass{l3doc} % compare with article class
\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=lists]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, main]{american}
\babelprovide[import, mapdigits]{persian}
\babelfont[persian]{rm}[Renderer = Harfbuzz]{Amiri}
\AddToHook{cmd/list/before}{\ifnum\pardirection=\pagedirection\else\shapemode=2\fi}
\begin{document}
\begin{list}{\leftmargin 1cm}
  \item\relax
    123
\end{list}

\medskip
\hrule

\selectlanguage{persian}
\begin{list}{\leftmargin 1cm}
\item\relax
  123
\end{list}
\end{document}


Ta! Presumably, babel patches this in with layout=lists, but as Ulrike mentioned the patch fails with l3doc. I just need it for one example, so setting \shapemode manually is fine for me.
